# Handling Label's Content changed event in wpf using MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf

This label is present in a User Control and I am binding this Label's Content property to Window's datacontext. I want to execute a ICommand whenever a Content of this Label changes. Property it is binded to is in Parent's ViewModel. While I have a ICommand in user control's viewmodel.

```
    <Label Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle}" 
         FontSize="28" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
         Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}, 
         Mode=FindAncestor}, Path=DataContext.CurrentTag}">
    </Label>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a cleaner approach that fits with MVVM pattern.

Interactivity is coming from below namespace

```
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
```

Setting `NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True`, enables `TargetUpdated` event to trigger where I bound my ICommand

```
 <Label Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle}" FontSize="28" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
             Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}
                        ,Mode=FindAncestor}
            , Path=DataContext.CurrentTag, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}" >
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="TargetUpdated">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SubmitCommand}" 
                                           CommandParameter="{Binding 
                               RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}
                                ,Mode=FindAncestor}, Path=DataContext.CurrentTag}" />
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </Label>
```

Comment: I am getting one issue here, I am getting old value in ICommand however I was looking for newValue

Answer (score 0):

The `Label` has no ContentChanged event to handle.

What you could do is to use a `DependencyPropertyDescriptor` and hook up an event handler using its `AddValueChanged` method programmatically:

```
public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
    public MyUserControl ()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = new YourViewModelClass();

        DependencyPropertyDescriptor dpd = DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(Label.ContentProperty, typeof(Label));
        if (dpd != null)
        {
            dpd.AddValueChanged(label, OnLabelContentChanged);
        }
    }

    private void OnLabelContentChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var vm = this.DataContext as YourViewModelClass;
        vm.YourCommand.Execute(null);
    }
}
```

**Handling changes to dependency properties in the view:** https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2014/03/31/handling-changes-to-dependency-properties/

```
<Label x:Name="label"
         FontSize="28" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
         Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}, 
         Mode=FindAncestor}, Path=DataContext.CurrentTag}">
</Label>
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before, `Label` has no `ContentChanged` event.

However, when I needed this property to work I have used `SizeChanged` Event instead.

What I did was whenever I change the `Label`'s Content, I have changed the width of it with a value that close to original width.

Since `Label` does not show the edges, It does not matter that how much your `Label` long, unless you do not have any other tool near it.

I know this is not the exact and formal solution for this problem, but It saved my day.

Answer (score 0):

`Label` has no `ContentChanged` event as already said but `TextBox` does have a [`TextChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.textboxbase.textchanged?view=windowsdesktop-5.0) event.

If you disable the [`IsHitTestVisible`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement.ishittestvisible?view=windowsdesktop-5.0#System_Windows_UIElement_IsHitTestVisible) and turn the `BorderBrush` and `Background` invisible then it looks almost the same as a Label and is not writeable so it also functions the same.